# Get download link of file in Service Account Google API

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, service-accounts

I am successful in uploading files with Service Account. I used auth Service account to upload, list, and update files.

I can't see the files in browser. Only my app can view it. But how can I get a download link for the file uploaded?

Anyone can help me and give me a guide to get download link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that a service account is not you.  A service account is a dummy user you are uploading files to the service accounts Google drive account.  The files it uploads will then be owned by it.

The file resource should contain one of these links. You can use them to show the file to another user.

> - Link a user to a file — webContentLink from the [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource) (download)
> - Link a user to a file - webViewLink form [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource) (will open in the Google drive website)
>
> webViewLink    string  A link for opening the file in a relevant Google editor or viewer in a browser.
>
> webContentLink string  A link for downloading the content of the file in a browser. This is only available for files with binary content in Drive.

You may have to either have the service account set the file to public or share it with you before you will be able to use either of those links. check [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions)

Comment: I can't view it. If I set it to public? Other people can view the file with webContentLink right? but if using Browser Google Drive, they can't view it because the file is not shared to them?

Comment: Yup they should be able to

Answer (score 0):

com.google.api.services.drive.model.File document = null;

```
try {
     document = serrvice.files().get(googleFileId).setFields("*").execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

then API returns full resources of file. This is for v3 drive API.

If u use v2 drive api use :

```
try {
     document = serrvice.files().get(googleFileId).execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

then API returns full resources of file.